# Access a variable declared in beforeCreate() from created() in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have created a variable in `beforeCreate()` hook in Vue likie this:

```
beforeCreate() {
    let companies = store.dispatch('getCompanies');
}
```

Now, I want to access this `companies` variable (which is a promise) in `created()` hook

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make it a data property, like so:

```
data() {
   return {
       companies: undefined
   }
},
beforeCreate() {
    this.companies = store.dispatch('getCompanies');
},
created() {
    console.log(this.companies) // or whatever
}
```

Comment: `this.companies` is undefined in `created()` hook also :(

Comment: I got it... I just changed the variable name in `beforeCreate()` from `this.companies` to `this.companiesData`. The variable name declared in `data()` property should be different from the variable name declared in `beforeCreate()`. Anyway thanks :)

Comment: can I defined the companies variable at beforeCreate, and redefined it at data? when I use it ,what's the result ?